# Add a row with total in Log Analytics Kusto query

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I query a request log for a summary of status codes. However I would like to add a row at the end of the results, showing the total number of requests. How do I add such a row?

Current query (simplified)

```
MyLog
| summarize count() by responseCode
```

Current result looks like

| responseCode | count |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | 1000 |
| 404 | 20 |
| 500 | 100 |

I would like to have the totals like this

| responseCode | count |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | 1000 |
| 404 | 20 |
| 500 | 100 |
| total | 1120 |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could try this:

```
MyLog
| summarize c = count() by responseCode
| as hint.materialized=true T
| union (T | summarize c = sum(c) by responseCode = "total")
```

or this:

```
MyLog
| summarize c = count() by responseCode
| union (print responseCode = "total", c = toscalar(MyLog | count))
```

if you want to keep the 'total' row last, you can order the unioned data set. for example:

```
MyLog
| summarize c = count() by responseCode
| extend _o = 0
| union (
    print responseCode = "total",
          c = toscalar(MyLog | count),
          _o = 1
)
| order by _o asc, c desc
| project-away _o
```

Comment: I don't suppose there's a way to keep this row at the bottom of the table when the columns are sorted?

Comment: you'll have to order the unioned data set according to the order of your choice. see updated answer with an example